# C++ Custom Inheritance in private, public and protected

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it possible to have protected inherited members automatically be protected in a derived class, as well as the inherited public members to automatically be public in the same derived class?

For Example:

If I have a base class `A`, and it has some protected and public members, and I choose to create a Derived class `B`, which inherits from `A`, then is it possible to automatically put the inherited protected members in the protected category, and the inherited public members in the public category within `A` (instead of doing `class B : public A` - which makes all inherited members public).

I understand that I can do `using Base::var` manually but I am looking for a quicker solution.

I have visual assist too.

Comment: Rereading this several times, what exactly makes you think that this doesn't already work this way?

Comment: See https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/public-protected-private-inheritance When you use `public` inheritance, public members stay public, protected members stay protected.

Comment: I did not know this. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the representation of inherited members after inheritance:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     |                    DERIVED CLASS VIS.                    |
|   BASE CLASS VIS.   |----------------------------------------------------------+
|                     | PUBLIC DER.      | PRIVATE DER.     | PROTECTED DER.     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Private     =>      | Not inherited    | Not inherited    | Not inherited      |
| Protected   =>      | Protected        | Private          | Protected          |
| Public      =>      | Public           | Private          | Protected          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

On public inheritance:

```
class B : public A
```

1. The private members of base class is NOT derived into the derived class.
2. The protected members of the base class IS derived into the derived class BUT protected.
3. The public members of the base class are ALSO derived into the derived class AND public that they're accessing from outside of the class.